# Ссылка на dll из главного проекта

Tags: c#, dll, project

Имеется решение, состоящее из множества проектов. Главный проект - MDI-контейнер. Остальные проекты - dll подключаемых форм - зависимые.
В большинстве  dll будет использоваться подключение к базе данных MySQL, соответственно в каждой должна быть ссылка на библиотеку MySQL и  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
Однако, в случае изменения версии файла библиотеки MySQL  все это дело может перестать работать. Или при изменении версии потребуется поменять версию файла по всех подключаемых dll.
Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы зависимые проекты брали ссылку на библиотеку или пространство имен из основного проекта?

Answer (score 3):

> В большинстве dll будет использоваться подключение к базе данных MySQL, соответственно в каждой должна быть ссылка на библиотеку MySQL и using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Вот здесь ваша главная ошибка. Работу с базой данных надо выносить в отдельный слой (в данном случае в отдельную dll), а наружу из него выставлять только интерфейсы никак не связанные с конкретным сервером БД. Тогда вам не придется перетряхивать все свои проекты.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ли вы InversionOfControl архитектуру. Их есть разные реализации Castle Windsor, Autofac, MEF, Unity.